# How to double all the values in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double(lst):
    for x in lst:
        x *= 2
        print x
    return lst

print double(n)
```

Why doesn't this return `n = [6, 10, 14]`?

There should also be a better solution that looks something like `[x *=2 for x in lst]` but it doesn't work either.

Any other tips about for-loops and lists would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why doesn't this return `n = [6, 10, 14]`?

Because `n`, or `lst` as it is called inside `double`, is never modified. `x *= 2` is equivalent to `x = x * 2` for numbers `x`, and that only re-binds the *name* `x` without changing the object it references.

To see this, modify `double` as follows:

```
def double(lst):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        x *= 2
        print("x = %s" % x)
        print("lst[%d] = %s" % (i, lst[i]))
```

To change a list of numbers in-place, you have to reassign its elements:

```
def double(lst):
    for i in xrange(len(lst)):
        lst[i] *= 2
```

If you don't want to modify it in-place, use a comprehension:

```
def double(lst):
    return [x * 2 for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double(lst):
    for x in lst:
        x *= 2
        print x # item value changed and printed
    return lst # original lst returned

print double(n)
```

you only modified item value inside a list and printed its number but returning original lst list.
`[x *=2 for x in lst]` is wrong syntax, the correct way to write is `[x*2 for x in lst]`.
Another way is to use lambda with map:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x*2,[1,2,3])))
```

Note: `print((lambda x:x*2)([1,2,3]))` will give wrong answer, it outputs in `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` same as doing `[1,2,3]*2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for this:

***FUNCTION:***

```
def double(lst):
    return [i*2 for i in lst]
```

***DEMO:***

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
print(double(n))
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
[6, 10, 14]
```

In python multiplying a list itself will produce this:

```
print([1, 2]*4)
# [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Therefore what you need is to multiply the items of the list, that's why you use for-loop in the first place, to iterate thru the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you modify `x`; however, modifying `x` doesn't change the elements of the list.

If you want to multiply every element by two, use map:

```
map(lambda(x):x*2, lst)
```

Comment: I have yet to figure out how to use map. Thanks though.

Comment: Basically, you apply the function to every element of the list.  The function is the first argument of `map`, and the list is in the second.

Comment: I would suggested that a list comprehension is the more Pythonic approach to the problem presented.

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension solution looks differently:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
n = [x*2 for x in n]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = [2,3,4,5,10]                         
def double_ult(lst):
    y = []                        
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] *= 2
        y += [lst[i]]                     
    return y

print(double_ult(a_list))
```

result:
[4, 6, 8, 10, 20]

with  .append() method:

```
b_list = [2,3,4,5,10]
def double_append(lst):
    y = []
    for i in lst:
        lst = 2 * i
        y.append(lst)
    return y

print(double_append(b_list))
```

result:
[4, 6, 8, 10, 20]

enter code here

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this code to double your elements in the list:

a_list = [3, 5, 7]

multiplied_list = [element * 2 for element in a_list]

print(multiplied_list)

Output = [6, 10, 14

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This solution is already proposed in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17659809/6682517) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345892/6682517) including the [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17659811/6682517). Please make sure that your contribution adds something new to the question or the answers before posting it.